# Select by ResultHandler will put a empty list objcet in localCache

Tags: mybatis

### MyBatis version

3.5.4

### Database vendor and version

MySQL 5.7.14

### Test case or example project

```
public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myTest?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false";
  public static final String Driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
  public static final String User_Name = "root";
  public static final String Password = "";

  public static void main(String[] args) {

DataSource dataSource = new PooledDataSource(Driver,URL, User_Name,Password);
    TransactionFactory transactionFactory = new JdbcTransactionFactory();
    Environment environment = new Environment("development", transactionFactory, dataSource);
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration(environment);
    configuration.addMapper(BlogMapper.class);
    SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(configuration);
    SqlSession sqlSession = sqlSessionFactory.openSession();

    sqlSession.select("selectCount",resultContext -> {
      System.out.println(resultContext.getResultCount());
      System.out.println(resultContext.getResultObject());
    });

    Object c = sqlSession.selectOne("selectCount");
    System.out.println(c);
}
```

```
public interface BlogMapper {

  @Select("select count(*) from datas")
  public int selectCount();
}
```

### Steps to reproduce

### Expected result

Object c = sqlSession.selectOne("selectCount");
selectOne function should retuen result ，but return null.

### Actual result

sqlSession.selectOne("selectCount"); return null

Comment: Do you actually have such usage in your real-world application...? Anyway, if you really have to do that, you must configure `localCacheScope` to `STATEMENT` in the config.

Comment: yes，but i think this is a bug. although localCacheScope is SESSION, 'selectOne' function should return a cache value,howerer,it return a null value.

Comment: If you use `ResultHandler`, the result is not cached. This behavior is clearly [documented](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/java-api.html). `ResultHandler` is designed to provide a way for users to write a custom mapping logic and it is not intended to call the same statement with and without `ResultHandler`, I would think.

Comment: i konw the feature ，the result is not cached.  but why the 'selectOne' function get a null value?  this is a bug ?.?

Comment: It's 'unintended usage'. :) If you have to call `select("selectCount", resultHandler)` and `selectOne("selectCount")` in the same session, set `localCacheScope=STATEMENT` or call `sqlSession.clearCache();` before the second call.

Comment: i think ,in this function "BaseExecutor.java#queryFromDatabase()"  .
should add  a  line code 

if (resultHandler==null){
      localCache.putObject(key, list);
    }

Comment: That if statement will be evaluated for every call, so every user is affected by that change.  Given that this usage is unintended and there are relatively easy workarounds, I would prefer not to make such change.